# Alternate operations for addition on $\mathbb{R}$ that keep the ring structure with multiplication

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

What are the operations $\oplus$ on $\mathbb{R}$ that can replace the addition, while keeping the ring structure with multiplication ?

Or, to generalize a bit: what are the operations $\oplus$ on positive reals ($\mathbb{R}_{>0}$) such that ($\mathbb{R}_{>0}, \oplus)$ is a cancellative commutative semigroup, and $\times$ distributes over $\oplus$?
Then we can probably extend with $0$ as neutral for $\oplus$, add inverse elements for $\oplus$, and define multiplication on them by $(\ominus a)\times b \stackrel {\text{def}} = \ominus (a \times b)$.

---

Some operations that work are $a \oplus b \stackrel {\text{def}} = (a^p + b^p)^{1/p}$, for $p \in \mathbb{R}$, $p \neq 0$. **Are they the only ones?**

(If they are the only ones, maybe it could be proved using Cauchy's functional equation, where the regularity to avoid pathological solutions would come from distributivity?)

Notes on these $(a^p + b^p)^{1/p}$ operations:

- $\oplus$ derives from $+$ by the $f(x) = x^p$ bijection from $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ to itself. Equivalently, one can use a $\log$ to go from $+$ to $\times$, then a $\log$ with a different base and on the opposite direction: this gives one of those $\oplus$ operations.
- When $p$ is an odd integer, $\oplus$ with $\times$ is a ring on $\mathbb{R}$.
- When $p \rightarrow +\infty$, $a \oplus b$ converges pointwise to $\max(a,b)$, and when $p \rightarrow -\infty$, $a \oplus b$ converges pointwise to $\min(a,b)$. $\max$ and $\min$ lose the cancellation property, but multiplication is still distributive upon them.
- $(a^p + b^p)^{1/p}$ reminds of the $p$-norm (for $p > 1$): this is not a coincidence, but I won't extend this already too long question any further :-).

Comment: Even on $\mathbb{Z}$, there are other ring structures with the same multiplication. Indeed, the multiplicative monoids of $\mathbb{Z}$ and of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ (polynomials) are isomorphic, because both rings are UFDs with countably many primes and only $\pm{1}$ as units. So, the ring structure on $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ transports to one on $\mathbb{Z}$ with the usual multiplication but a different addition.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang Thanks! I am not much familiar with polynomial rings. So if I want an example of a different addition on $\mathbb{Z}$, the recipe is: take the list of irreductible polynomials of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, map them to the primes in $\mathbb{Z}$, then look at what the addition in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ gives in $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: The operation $a \oplus b=(a^p+b^p)^{1/p}$ is the conjugate of $+$ by the multiplicative automorphism $f(x)=x^p$. There are $2^{\aleph_0}$ multiplicative automorphisms of the form $f(x)=x^p$. But there are $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ multiplicative automorphisms of $(\mathbb R_{>0},\cdot)$ altogether, so there are a lot more distinct conjugates of $+$ than you have indicated.

Comment: @KeithKearnes Thanks. If I understand well, multiplicative automorphisms of $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ are given by permutations of a basis of $\mathbb{R}$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$ vector space. The answer here is also handy: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3147683/group-automorphism-of-multiplicative-group-of-real-number-field

Comment: This is an interesting question. One thing I noticed is that the map $(-)\otimes 0:\mathbb \to\mathbb R$ satisfies Cauchy functional equation, but I guess you already figured that out