# multiplicative involution other than conjugation

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, complex-numbers

I have given a function $\varphi : \mathbb{C} \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ which is a multiplicative involution with fixed point $1$ i.e.

1. $\varphi(\varphi(z)) = z$
2. $\varphi(a\cdot b) = \varphi(a)\cdot \varphi(b) $
3. $\varphi(1) = 1$

can it be shown, that it must be complex conjugation? I.e. that $\varphi(z) = \overline{z}$ for all $z$? Clearly $z \mapsto \overline{z}$ satisfies all those properties, but is it unique?
Edit: Also $\varphi$ is *not* the identity function.

Comment: I don't know but when I see products, I think logs. (Though keep in mind the complexities of complex logarithms)

Comment: I inadvertently clicked on -1 on my phone, sorry for that. Now I would like to click on +1 because your question is worth it, but cannot (unless you edit the question, but I don't want to push you to edit the question for nothing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Let $\varphi : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ be the function defined by $\varphi(z) = z/|z|^2$ if $z \neq 0$ and $\varphi(0) = 0$. Then $\varphi$ is multiplicative, since if $z,w \in \mathbb{C}$ are non-zero, then
$$
\varphi(zw) = \frac{z}{|z|^2}\frac{w}{|w|^2} = \frac{zw}{|zw|^2} = \varphi(zw)
$$
and if otherwise if one of $z$ or $w$ are zero, then clearly $\varphi(zw) = \varphi(0) = 0 = \varphi(z)\varphi(w)$. Observe $\varphi(1) = 1/|1|^2 = 1$, so it fixes $1$ and it has order 2 since for any $z \in \mathbb{C}-\{0\}$,
$$
\varphi(\varphi(z)) =\varphi \left( \frac{z}{|z|^2} \right) = \frac{z/|z|^2}{|z/|z|^2|^2} = \frac{z|z|^4}{|z|^2|z|^2} = z
$$

Clearly $\varphi$ is not complex conjugation (since it does not fix $\mathbb{R}$, as for example, $\varphi(2) = \frac{1}{2}$). It may be useful to observe that all non-zero complex numbers can be written as $\lambda e^{\theta}$ for some $\lambda > 0$ and $e^{\theta} \in \mathbb{T}$. So if we can find a multiplicative involution $\sigma$ on $(\mathbb{R}_{>0},\times)$ that fixes $1$ and a multiplicative involution $\tau$ on $\mathbb{T}$ that fixes $1$, then one could hope that the function $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$, $\lambda e^{\theta} \mapsto \sigma(\lambda)\tau(e^{\theta})$ and $0 \mapsto 0$ would provide a counterexample. This is how I produced $\varphi$, by taking $\tau(z) = z$ and $\sigma(x) = x^{-1}$ in the above.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot :)

Comment: So now we have $4$ continuous solutions (id, conjugate, your solution, its conjugate). Could there be a continuum-infinity of other solutions, mixing those $4$ ones on a basis.of $\mathbb{C}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$? In the spirit of this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3147683/group-automorphism-of-multiplicative-group-of-real-number-field